# With Carcasonne crop circles expansion, which meeples count as followers?

Tags: carcassonne

When deploying extra followers from a crop circle action, I'm not sure which meeple count as followers. The [CAR](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/87531/carcassonne-standard-complete-annotated-rules) states that players may take one of their own followers from their supply and deploy it next to another of their followers already on a landscape tile. It also reads that players must deploy the follower to a feature which already contains a follower of the same type (farmer to a farmer, thief to a thief, knight to a knight).

This would exclude the builder or wagon, I suppose. But not the big follower... But the mayor would count as a knight when it's in a city. Does it, however, count as a follower in your supply?

**Which meeples can be placed onto the board next to another follower, as the result of an action from a crop circle?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a clarification on page 206 of the rules you link to.

**Followers**

Every normal follower, big follower, mayor, wagon, or phantom follower is just one follower.

**Special figures**

Builders, pigs, barns, and shepherds belong to individual players but are not followers."

So if you are adding a follower with crop circles you may add any of the followers. The only exception to this being a Mayor can only be placed as a Knight in a city.